# Higher mixed partial derivatives of $e^{f(x)}$

Tags: derivatives

I have a function $g(x) = e^{-f(x)}$, $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. Is there some compact and beautiful formula for the derivative $\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}...\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}g(x)?$ Maybe in the case of $n=2$?

Comment: I doubt it. Once you take any first partial derivative of $g $, you get a product of functions and I can only see things getting uglier.

Comment: For $n=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$ you have to introduce Hermite polynomials. So we are not optimistic for a nice general formula.

Comment: But maybe it can be written in nice form via symbols $\sum$ and $\prod$ (something like Faa di Bruno formula)?

Comment: Here I've found some generalisation of Faa di Bruno formula. I'll try with it. http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_16/PDF/v16i1n21.pdf

Comment: The short answer is "yes".  I'll post a longer answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You suggest $n=2$.  Here it is if $n=3$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x_1\;\partial x_2\;\partial x_3} e^{f(x_1,x_2,x_3)} & = e^{f(x_1,x_2,x_3)} \left( \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_1\;\partial x_2\;\partial x_3} \right. \\  \\  \\  \\
& {} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2\;\partial x_3} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\;\partial x_3} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\;\partial x_2} \\  \\  \\  \\
& \left.{} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} \right).
\end{align}
$$
The idea is to **run through the list of all (unordered) partitions of the set of variables**.  If two or more of the variables happen to be the same variable, e.g. if one wants $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial x_1\;\partial x_2^2}e^{f(x_1,x_2)}$, then just identify the two indices $2$ and $3$, so that some of the terms in the expansion become the same as each other.

Here's an excercise: Proof this by induction on the number of variables.

And look up the term "exponential formula" in Richard Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*, volume 2.  He gives the formal-power-series version of the formula, where the partial derivatives are coefficients in the power series.

**Later note:** OK, I've momentarily stopped being lazy and located the paper I wrote about this and closely related topics: http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_13/v13i1toc.html

It's the very first paper in the volume for the year 2006.

In particular, see the bottom of page 3.

Quoting:
$$
\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x_1\cdots\partial x_n} e^y = e^y \sum_\pi \prod_{B\in\pi} \frac{\partial^{|B|}y}{\prod_{j\in B}\partial x_j} 
$$
where the sum is over all partitions $\pi$ of the set $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and the product is over all the parts $B$ of the partition $\pi$, and $|B|$ is the number of members of $B$.

Comment: One can generalize this to arbitrary mixed partials with the same exact formula by considering *multisets* and subsequently *partitions of multisets*. (And as it turns out, I see that's what you actually did in your paper. Nice.)

Comment: Great thanks, your article http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_13/PDF/v13i1r1.pdf perfectly clarifies situation!